# Connecting with SSH doesnt work

Tags: ssh

I have to connect to this server for school. But it wont work. What can I try? You see the problem below. I am a beginner at linux ubuntu, so I would prefer perfectly described orders :D

```
luka@luka-Lenovo-Flex-2-14:~$ ssh 
"theservername"
The authenticity of host 'theservername' ("IPAdress")' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 6e:3e:60:da:e0:0c:45:42:be:48:cb:ff:a10:a4:4b:98.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: Try to ssh with password based authentication first before trying RSA key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the key authenticity on there side.  Server side must have an authorized key from you.  I would ask what method of authenticity they want, but most likely it is a key.  Here is the documentation for that.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Basically you type.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Output will be like..

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A
```

then copy the key file to the school machine. It will be a .pub file in your .ssh directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you have a few issues here. One, you're just ssh'ing into the server without a username, which makes it automatically select "luka" as the username. This would make your command be `ssh user@server`. And when it asks about authenticity of the RSA key, type yes. Also, make sure to contact whoever gave you the server details and ask what your username/password on the server is.